# wicket; images from file system. I added resourse folder, and still working

Tags: image, resources, wicket

What I want is adding resource folder from file system for storing images and displaying them. I added the folder in the Application, and still working.

WicketTestApplication#init

```
getResourceSettings().getResourceFinders().add( new WebApplicationPath( getServletContext(), "C:\\image" ) );
```

And TestPage

```
public class TestPage extends WebPage {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public TestPage() {
    add( new ContextImage( "image", "C:/image/rhodes.jpg" ) );  
  }
}
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebApplicationPath` is a `IResourceFinder` that will look for resources in the web application path, except in `WEB-INF/` folder. So you cannot use it to load something from your file system.

I'd suggest you to use `FileSystemResource[Reference]` instead or a specialization of `DynamicImageResource`.

```
private static class ImageResource extends DynamicImageResource {

   @Override
   protected byte[] getImageData(Attributes attributes) {

       PageParameters parameters = attributes.getParameters();
       StringValue name = parameters.get("name");

       byte[] imageBytes = null;

       if (name.isEmpty() == false) {
           imageBytes = getImageAsBytes(name.toString());
       }
       return imageBytes;
   }

   private byte[] getImageAsBytes(String imageName) {
      // read the image from the file system, e.g. with FileInputStream(folder, imageName);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object that) {
       return that instanceof ImageResource;
   }
}
```

An article explaining this approach can be found at: http://wicketinaction.com/2011/07/wicket-1-5-mounting-resources/

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if you believe it helps you!